# Are there any ways to get a bonus feat that are not class or race restrictive in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

Specific feats I'm looking for are Endurance and Iron Will, since I figure those would be the most likely, or Psionic Meditation, Psionic Weapon, or Unlocked Talent.  All but Unlocked Talent are required for PrC class entry so I can't have them on a weapon or anything.  I hope to gain all 5 of these feats before level 5 and I am getting one bonus combat or teamwork feat as is.  The reason for the Unlocked Talent feat is to meet a manifesting a specific power requirement so that does not need to be actually on my feat list but expanding on that is grounds for another question.

Answer (score 2):

If your game uses the anti-hero optional rule for the hero points optional rule system you can gain a non-class, non-race, non-level-derived bonus feat.  This is the only way to gain an intrinsic bonus feat without spending class or race resources on it.

If you are a half-elf or can pretend to be one *[Paragon Surge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/paragon-surge)*, by far the best spell in the game before the nerf-bat hit it, can get you another 'feat for which you meet the prerequisites' which is effectively a bonus feat.  It only lasts 1 minute/level so it's not too useful to you.

You can get tons of feats from ioun stones, which would let you qualify for class entry, but you stated that you aren't interested in equipment based solutions so we wont go into detail on that.

Comment: I always thought equipment based solutions don't qualify you for class entry or taking other feats or similar permanent gains that need a certain prerequisite.

Comment: @Dorian In the case of other feats, they work fine, you just have more to lose if you lose the item (because losing the prerequisite also loses the feat that required it). RAW, this is somewhat more ambiguous with PrCs, but in your case, assuming this is for the campaign we're both in, the DM has ruled that items can't provide PrC prerequisites. Still might matter for the next person to have the same question, though, so still worth covering here

Comment: @Dorian If you're avoiding items because of DM ruling, your DM probably isn't going to be happy with some kind of extended/continual paragon surge as a PrC prerequisite either, so you're pretty much left with the first option.

Comment: Yeah I don't think any of these options are going to work in the campaign.  Good answer though at least.